# Help me remember "memory recording" movie: not "Memento", not "Final Cut"

Tags: story-identification

I need to remember the title of a old movie I've seen 15/20 years ago or something.
I remember these main facts:

1. looks weird like a Cronenberg movie, but looking at his filmography the title doesn't pop out.
2. it is in a post-modern ambientation, the facts take place in the near future but all the furniture and fashion are 1940/1950 style, but mixed with color tvs, tapes, blinking ligths etc.
3. there was a large wooden decorated machine where the main character had to sit in front of, and record/view memories gathered from other people.
4. should be a movie from the eighties

Everyone tells me that is MEMENTO (no wooden machine unit, and it's not 1950's style) or THE FINAL CUT (far too recent). It's NOT "strange days" either!!!

Comment: This looks more like a question for MoviesSE.

Comment: I suppose we can rule out the 1983 movie "brainstorm" as well? The props in that movie looks like a mishmash of styles. https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=NNiZP2G-nEM

Comment: No, it's not Brainstorm, it's too techy. The movie I've got in mind is more like, like "naked lunch" but with sci-fi bits.
The focal point is the machinery that the main actor uses, that resembles a wooden organ but with TVS and tape/discs slots to interact [https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3b/00/eb/3b00eb2cf062176f52760d39bb4aa22c.jpg

Comment: *Ambientation*? What language is that and what does it mean in English?

Comment: Yes, of course is a north american movie, regular distribution etc. Sorry but I was a kid when I saw it, probably it IS strange-days or memento.. and I've mixed up things.
However, I feel really sure about this guy (a la Constantine, probably a cop or a private investigator) dealing with this steampunk huge wooden console, used to mess with other people memories or dreams or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

Might be a long shot but are you thinking of Brasil?
It had that 40's/50's style, tapes and tv's, etc... and had that Cronenberg feel.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_(1985_film)

Answer (score 5):

Another long shot, but was it maybe [The City of Lost Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_of_Lost_Children)?

- Strange in a Cronenberg sort of way
- Main "bad guy" harvests dreams from children using ornate steampunk/Rube Goldberg machinery
- old-fashioned ambience

Answer (score 3):

There was a low-budget version of Varley's [*Overdrawn at the Memory Bank*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089759/) made in the 80s, inexplicably starring Raul Julia. Besides the time frame and low budget elements, the theme of memory manipulation /VR makes this a possible match. You can see the [MST3K version on YouTube here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVo0dyjnWYo)

Comment: LOL that looks interesting! but no, it was a "serious" movie, not particularly low budget. 
I assume I'm mixing up Strange Days with some other movie (the plot, afaik, fits like charm) but I really can't figure out why I'm so persuaded about the retro-steampunk wooden-console computer, where else may I have got it from? CREEPY T___T

Answer (score 3):

"Until the End of the World" (1991)?

Here is just part of the extremely long plot summation from Wikipedia which describes a memory viewing device.

> "There, Sam reveals that the stolen prototype belongs to his father,
>   Henry Farber and is a device for recording and translating brain
>   impulses. He has been recording places and people around the world for
>   his blind mother, Edith, but the recordings are exhausting his eyes. "

It has that Cronenbergian look, takes place in the near future, and has characters who dress in the styles of the '40s. Here is the trailer from YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Brainstorm (1983)

Stars: Christopher Walken, Natalie Wood, Louise Fletcher

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorm_(1983_film)

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085271/