# Trying to remember a movie with memory extraction

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been trying to remember a movie I watched many years ago, it had memory extraction, people would get money (I think) to have a chip implanted that would record their experience for a time, afterwards people would come and extract the device, killing them, and others could live these peoples experiences.

The only scene I can remember is people finding someone who went crazy living a girl's experience over and over, losing themselves in the memories.

If anyone has any ideas what movie this is, that would be great.

Edit: Was not Brainstorm, I remember it being more high tech then that, perhaps in the 90s, or early 2000s.
Something along the lines of Strange Days.

Comment: We've done this one before I think.

Comment: Are you sure that the people having their experiences recorded had to be killed? In "Strange Days" there was a similar setup and several people were killed, but it was not required by the process.

Comment: What's the matter? Did someone extract your memory? ;)

Comment: *Strange Days is a 1995 American science fiction thriller film directed by Kathryn Bigelow, written by James Cameron and Jay Cocks, and produced by Cameron and Steven-Charles Jaffe. It stars Ralph Fiennes, Angela Bassett, Juliette Lewis, and Tom Sizemore. Set in the last two days of 1999, the film follows the story of a black marketeer of SQUID discs, recordings that allow a user to experience the recorder's memories and physical sensations, as he attempts to uncover the truth behind the murder of a prostitute.* - Strange Days

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158442/movie-where-memory-is-switched-between-people-and-help-solve-a-murder/158443#158443 / https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105006/help-me-remember-memory-recording-movie-not-memento-not-final-cut / https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94540/movie-identification-people-record-their-experiences-on-reel-to-reel

Comment: I really do think they were killed in the extraction process, its been so long so I could be not remembering properly, but I thought they got paid allot to have their experiences recorded. "Stranger Days" looks similar but were there any other movies around that time that could fit the bill?

Comment: Possibly Brainstorm. The dupe mentions a tape that goes on a loop and kills people; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94540/movie-identification-people-record-their-experiences-on-reel-to-reel

Comment: @Valorum That's the one I was thinking we had. Good work!

Comment: I also immediately thought of Strange Days. People record their memories for money, pretty sure there's a scene where someone's mind is burnt out by having memories played back on a loop.

Answer (score 3):

This may be [*The Final Cut* (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364343/), which starred Robin Williams as a sort of film editor who cut together memories from people who were already dead (not killed by the extraction process), but who had had recording chips implanted during their life.  Extraction and editing was an expensive process, and required expertise -- but then a job comes up where the memories to be edited put the cutter in danger.